# jQuery chaining parent(), is there an easier way?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent, jquery-traversing

Hay, I have some markup like this

```
<div id="some-id">
    <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
</div>
```

and some jQuery like this

```
$(this).parent().parent().attr("id")
```

$(this) is referring to the 'a' tag within the 'h2'

Is there an easier way to select the parent div without using parent() twice. I tried

```
$(this).parent("div").attr("id")
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), like this:

```
$(this).closest("div").attr("id")
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WZTqX/).
[`.parent("div")`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) isn't as intuitive as it seems, it gets *only* the **immediate** parent *if* it matches the selector, [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) climbs the parents *until* it matches the selector.

Please note that (doesn't apply to this example) if `this` matches the selector, it returns *that* element, it doesn't *start* with the first parent, it starts with itself.

Comment: Does .closest() move up only? Or will it move down as well?

Comment: @dotty - It only goes to parents, if you want to find children use `.find()`, though you can only have one parent path, children can have many branches...so depends what you're after.